# How can I run the command "mcirotps_agent start -t UDP"?

Tags: linux, ros2, gazebo-simu

Hi i'm trying to install the rtps_bridge with linux.

but when I type the command like this:
me:~/lps_drone_sim$ . install/setup.bash
me:~/lps_drone_sim$ micrortps_agent start -t UDP

the terminal says like following:
micrortps_agent: command not found

I have unfortunately no idea how to fix this problem.

It will be very pleasure, if someone can help me.

thank you!

me:~/lps_drone_sim$ . install/setup.bash

me:~/lps_drone_sim$ micrortps_agent start -t UDP
micrortps_agent: command not found
me:~/lps_drone_sim$ . install/setup.bash
me:~/lps_drone_sim$ ros2 run drone_command control_gui
ros2: command not found